# undefined variable during insert data in mysql

Tags: php

at the beginning, it was display notice: undefined index, but after i put if(isset), it start to display notice:undefined variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['cid1']))
{
$cid1=$_POST['cid1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['pname1']))
{
$pname1=$_POST['pname1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['gen1']))
{
$gen1=$_POST['gen1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['ag1']))
{$ag1=$_POST['ag1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['add1'])){
$add1=$_POST['add1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['ad_dat1'])){$ad_dat1=$_POST['ad_dat1'];}

$my=mysql_query("insert into admission1(cid1, pname1, gen1, ag1, add1, ad_dat1) 
values('$cid1', '$pname1', '$gen1', '$ag1', '$add1', '$ad_dat1')") 
or die ('unable to  insert');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `var_dump($_POST);` and check out what keys are set.

Also you can use `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)` or `extract($_POST)` to make your code shorter.

Comment: Replace var_dump($_POST) with last 3 lines of your code. It will show you values of all post variables. Because now some of them are probably missing.